# Add role command Discord,js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to make an "add role" command with Discord.js. This is my code but the bot doesn't add the role.

```
if (message.content === config.prefix + 'addrole') {
    const targetUser = message.mentions.users.first()
    if (!targetUser) {
      message.reply('Please specify someone to give a role to.')
      return
    }
    const { guild } = message
    const role = guild.roles.cache.find((role) => {
      return role.name === roleName
    })

    if (!role) {
      message.reply(`There is no role with the name "${roleName}"`)
      return
    }

    const member = guild.members.cache.get(targetUser.id)
    member.roles.add(role)

    message.reply(`That user now has the "${roleName}" role`)
}
```

Can someone help me, please (I don't get any errors in the console)?

Answer (score 1):

`member_addrole` already returns a member object, so you can do this instead

```js
if (message.content == config.prefix + 'addrole') {
    let member_addrole = message.mentions.users.first();
    let remind_role = message.guild.roles.cache.find(mR => mR.name === "Remind ME");
    if (!member_addrole) return message.reply('no member provided');

    member_addrole.roles.add(remind_role);
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I also tried with another role but I doesn't work. Do you know another way to do it?

Comment: I edited the question with the new code. Also with that code it doesn't work. If you have Discord, please DM me at `Tomm#1946` as we can have an easier communication.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing entire code, member is not defined, and I assume you meant member_addrole.

However, you should also use guild from the message.

Looking at the last line this is not how you would add the role, check out my example I have put below.

You should also add checks to make sure a user is mentioned and that the role is found so you don't crash your bot.

Finally, you should run it in some sort of debugger so you can see where your code hits exceptions.

```
let member_addrole = message.mentions.users.first();
let remind_role = message.guild.roles.cache.find(mR => mR.name === "Remind ME");
await message.guild.members.cache.get(member_addrole.id).roles.add(remind_role);
```

Comment: I cannot comment on other's posts but @EJBEAN 's answer doesn't work (at least in my discord.js version) as `member_addrole.roles` is undefined

Comment: I tried with your code but it didn't work. Maybe there are problems with the position of the roles...

Comment: @fclinton added a fix, make sure u mention someone in your message, otherwise it will return undefined

Comment: My message in the channel is `;addrole @user`. Obviously I don't get any errors in the console because I mentioned a user. Maybe I have to use another function...

Comment: I edited the question with the new code. Also with that code it doesn't work. If you have Discord, please DM me at `Tomm#1946` as we can have an easier communication.

Comment: @Tomminss yeah, i have discord, im at work rn tho, ill send the req when i get home, also make sure the bot has permissions to view the channel & add roles